How to define the dynamic block to stretch correctly?
Being very new to AutoCAD (architecture) I am trying to define the following stretchable block:

My goal is to define the stretch so that the middle point stretches proporcionally. So far, the inner "V" stretches for me like this:

The bottom point of V should remain in the middle of the final distance.
I guess I should somehow lock the bottom point of the distance to another "Distance2" that should be set to be always one half of the "Distance1". But my idea can be completely wrong (being very new to AutoCAD).
Can you describe the principle of how that should be done? I do not understand the core ideas related to the stretch, yet.
Update: Another attempte (without the Distance2)... This time, the rectangle is visually created from 5 lines. The bottom edge of the rectangle is composed of the two separate lines (half length):

All objects except the leftmost vertical line were selected.


The result is wrong again. I may understand why it is wrong, but I do not know how to fix it.

Maybe it is easier to set the x scale; either while inserting the block or changing it via properties.

@ShahramAlemzadeh: How can I scale only in the x (that is, not also proprotionally in the y asis)?

1- When inserting a block by insert command, a dialog opens and there is a section to set the scale factor for each axis (default values are 1). 2- If the block is already inserted, select it and then right-click and choose the properties window. In the Geometry section you can set the scale factor for each axis.
